# How can I refresh my QWidget more than once a second using QTimer?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qwidget, qtimer

I want to build a GUI displaying imformation which is updated every 10-100 ms. I was trying to implement this into the QTimer example by stting Qtimer.start(100) but it keeps updating only once a second. How can achieve to refresh the GUI more than once a second? I also tried manual QWidget.update() and QTimer.setInterval(100) with no effect. Is there maybe any better solution?

```
import sys
from python_qt_binding.QtWidgets import QWidget,QPushButton,QApplication,QListWidget,QGridLayout,QLabel
from python_qt_binding.QtCore import Qt, QTimer,QDateTime

class RobolabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(RobolabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('QTimer example')

        self.listFile=QListWidget()
        self.label=QLabel('Label')
        self.startBtn=QPushButton('Start')
        self.endBtn=QPushButton('Stop')

        layout=QGridLayout()

        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)

        layout.addWidget(self.label,0,0,1,2)

        self.timer.start(100)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def showTime(self):
        time=QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        timeDisplay=time.toString('hh:mm:ss:ms')
        self.label.setText(timeDisplay)
```

Comment: the code looks fine to me... what error do you get hen running the python script?

Comment: I do not reproduce that error, what is your OS? Try adding `self.label.repaint()` after `self.label.setText(timeDisplay)`

Comment: I don't get an error. The label showing the time is just not updating every 100ms but every second. self.label.repaint() does not help either.
Im working on Ubuntu 18.04. Background is that i want to build a dashboard controlling and monitoring robots with ROS. The GUI is implemented as an rqt Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. QDateTime.currentDateTime() has only a resolution of seconds.

Instead of QDateTime I just use python-datetime function which works for me.